# Remove app from Location Services?

Tags: macos, security, system-settings

[image]I've used App Cleaner which clears preference and associated files, but I can't clear it from Location Services permissions list in System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy.

Any idea how to remove it?

Comment: When you click on Location Services in the Privacy tab does the program show up in the list? Is the lock icon in the lower left corner of the window unlocked, allowing you to make changes?

Comment: The program does show in the list, it is not removable however, locked or unlocked.

Comment: No solution? What a shame : (

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of Location Services in System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It took me a while to narrow down the file that contains the list of apps shown in that system pref pane, but I finally found.  The list of apps is stored in `/var/db/locationd/clients.plist`. Once I found that juicy bit of info a quick Google search revealed this related posting on superuser.com: [Remove Applications from Location Services in Security & Privacy on Mac OS X 10.8](https://superuser.com/questions/526183/remove-applications-from-location-services-in-security-privacy-on-mac-os-x-10). That post is more of an answer than a question. It contains detailed step-by-step instructions on how to remove the no longer installed app from the list.

Answer (score 7):

Came here looking for the same answer. I tried checking the box next to the item and once it was checked it disappeared from the list, so yrmv...

Comment: This solved my problem in macOS Catalina 10.15.6

Comment: And also for Catalina 10.15.7, after a lot of failed right clicking and Option-clicking. This is the correct answer.

Answer (score -1):

When you uncheck these options will automatically disappear (2021 MacBook air on m1).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).